# How to set up a user instead of using root Magento 2

Tags: magento2, permissions, user

I'm using root user to do everything which is throwing up problems. I know this is not the right way to do things. How do I set up a new user and set permissions?

Comment: Do you mean OS `root` user (for running CLI commands) or `admin` Magento user?

Comment: I mean OS root user

Comment: Please, see this document for information about file permissions - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html It includes explanation of the OS users used during Magento management

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a new role in Magento 2.0?**

1. System -> User Roles -> Add New Role and press Add New Role button.
2. Then write down the name of new Admin Role.
3. After that you can select to which resources you give access to this particular kind of user.
4. The last step in creating a new role in Magento 2.0 is to press the Save Role button.

**How to add new users in Magento 2.0 and assign roles to them?**

1. System -> All Users -> Add New User
2. We fill all the fields with required information.
3. Then we press User Role and select the role.
4. The last step is to press Save button.

Comment: Thats great thanks how do i select the user using the command line?

Comment: A single command (php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento list) lists all commands available